# Calling a function for every attribute I want to read from multiple .txt files and write to .csv file

Tags: batch-file

I tried to call a function for every attribute (column) that I want to read from 4 .txt files and then write into a .csv file. One column has flawed output and the code should have a few logic flaws as I haven't learned batch cleanly from scratch. Do you know a fix?

Link to previous solved question: [Read information from multiple .txt files and sort it into .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258020/read-information-from-multiple-txt-files-and-sort-it-into-csv-file)

@Magoo

[image: The result I got]

```
echo Name;Prename;Sign;Roomnumber;Phonenumber > sorted.csv

for /f  "tokens=1,2 delims= "  %%a in (TestEmployees.txt) do (
call :findSign %%a %%b
)

:findSign
set prename=%1
set name=%2

for /f  "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (TestSign.txt) do (
    if "%name%"=="%%a" (
      call :findRoomNumber
    )
)
    :End
    :findRoomNumber
    set sign=%1
    
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%q in (TestRoomNumber.txt) do (
            if "%sign%"=="%%q"    (
            
            call :findPhoneNumber
            )
        )
               :End
    :findPhoneNumber
    
                for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%u in (TestPhoneNumber.txt) do (
                    if "%%b"=="%%u"    (
                   
                        echo %name%;%prename%;%%b;%%r;%%v >> sorted.csv
                    )
                )
                    :End
```

Comment: I would like to write a better solution for your problem, However, I want _not_ to enter the data files to test my solution...

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load PhoneNumber array
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%a in (PhoneNumber.txt) do set "phone[%%a]=%%b"

rem Load RoomNumber array
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in (RoomNumber.txt) do set "room[%%a]=%%b"

rem Load Sign array
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (Sign.txt) do set "sign[%%a]=%%b"

rem Process Employees file and generate output
> sorted.csv (
   echo Name;Prename;Sign;RoomNumber;PhoneNumber
   for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (Employees.txt) do for %%s in (!sign[%%b]!) do (
      echo %%b;%%a;%%s;!room[%%s]!;!phone[%%s]!
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74258020_TestEmployees.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q74258020_TestSign.txt"
SET "filename3=%sourcedir%\q74258020_TestRoomNumber.txt"
SET "filename4=%sourcedir%\q74258020_TestPhoneNumber.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

>"%outfile%" (
 echo Surname;Name;Sign;Roomnumber;Phonenumber

 for /f "usebackqtokens=1,2 delims= "  %%g in ("%filename1%") do (  
  call :findSign %%g %%h
 )
)

GOTO :eof

:findSign
for /f  "usebackqtokens=1,2 delims= " %%b in ("%filename2%") do (
  if "%2"=="%%b" (
    for /f  "usebackqtokens=1,2 delims=|" %%q in ("%filename3%") do (
     if "%%c"=="%%q" (
        for /f  "usebackqtokens=1,2 delims=;" %%u in ("%filename4%") do (
          if "%%c"=="%%u" (
            echo %2;%1;%%c;%%r;%%v
          )
    )
      )
    )
  )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2128947) Copy and paste the code as text

For similar reasons, please post all relevant data into a question to obviate every potential respondent having to switch back and forth to the data to which you have linked.